# MoPub Alternative

Tags: ipad, mobile, ads, mopub, revenue

I am developing a system which has both Tablet & Website. 
It's a tool and now more and more professional come to register on my system.

I want to do ads on the system. Both website and Tablet(iPad for now but will support android).
I searched a lot and MoPub seems a good option. I did utilize the MoPub SDK to iOS and website. it works good except, it's for mobile only.(Said by MoPub official, I feel sad because it meet every my requirement except this one. I need do ads on website also, even on PC browser.)

I want find an alternative of MoPub, but seems there is not much options.
Is there any one who knows this and give me some suggestion?

My requirement is:

- As the system admin, I can create Ads order for customer, I can define the Ads content&layout displayed on both iPad & website. I can put link on ads and the link should works on both Tablet App and PC website.
- As developer who integrate the Ads platform. I can utilize the SDK to request Ads based on customer keywords I defined.
- I can see a lot of reports for the revenue, daily, monthly, single ads, multiple ads.
- The very basic Ads configuration
- Well formed SDK on iOS and android. so that I can integrate quickly.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

hey man) you’re asking and trying to compare different things: you ask about MoPub Alternative and one of your requirements is that the solution should support both Web and Mobile. MoPub is for mobile platforms (ios/android) only. Frankly speaking both web and mobile ads have own features and nuances, that’s why most of current solutions are focused either on mobile or web. Not sure I can provide lots of info about platforms for web, but this article might be useful for you https://www.adpushup.com/blog/the-best-ad-networks-for-publishers-2015-edition-moving-beyond-adsense/

Mopub is a really good platform, but if you’re still thinking about alternative (i’m speaking about mobile) take a look at mediation solutions. there are lots of them: AdMob Mediation, Heyzap, Fyber, Appodeal and many others. all of them have pros and cons. if you like manual customization and settings give a try to the first three, i’ve heared lots of good things and positive reviews about HeyZap and Fyber, though im not a big fan of "handjob" =). this way you’ll just have to create accounts in networks you’d like to use in mediation. but i personally think that its slightly a longer way, at least for me, because the performance of each network depends on your app and it need to be understood. so you’ll need to analyze which ad networks perform better for you.  i’m not a big fan of everyday analysis and comparisons, so i stick to programmatic services, like Appodeal for instanse. the point is that it works out of the box, automatically, without manual settings for each network and account, that helped me to save a lot of time for working on other projects. i’m pretty much sure that you won’t get a 100% right answer, because each developer has own priorities and aims. I suppose that the best way it to collect info on forums like stackoverflow, reddit, and make your own research accordin to your needs. good luck

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but seems not what I want.  I am looking for an option  beyond MoPub which support both website & mobile, but will contain MoPub features.  I am not confident that it was there now. But if not, I will build it myself. Any suggestion on how to build it  is welcome!